# TypeScript DeepMap Union type with if statement

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement, union-types

I'm trying to create a Union type with the structure of optional fields. I have created the following types:

```js
export type StartEndType = {
  start_date: string;
  end_date: string;
};

export type PayrollContract = StartEndType & {
  type: 'ON_PAYROLL';
  yearly_holidays: number;
};

export type FreelanceContract = StartEndType & {
  type: 'FREELANCE';
  hourly_rate: number;
};

export type Contract = PayrollContract | FreelanceContract;
```

In my component it looks like:

```js
{contractType === 'ON_PAYROLL' ? (
  <Number name="yearly_holidays"  />
) : contractType === 'FREELANCE' && (
  <Number name="hourly_rate" />
)}
```

When I hover contract, it knows that it's one of `ON_PAYROLL` or `FREELANCE`. Although unfortunately I get a DeepMap error within my component.

Isn't thist supported by TypeScript out of the box?

```js
Property 'yearly_holidays' does not exist on type 'DeepMap<PayrollContract, FieldError> | DeepMap<FreelanceContract, FieldError>'.
  Property 'yearly_holidays' does not exist on type 'DeepMap<FreelanceContract, FieldError>'.
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide the code for `Number` component? Looks like an issue with how you are rendering the number by name, I was able to compile and use the TS code above fine in TS playground.

```
const renderPayField = (contract: Contract) => {
  if (contract.type === 'ON_PAYROLL') {
     return <Number name="yearly_holidays" />;
  }
  if (contract.type === 'FREELANCE') {
     return <Number name="hourly_rate" />
  }
  return null;
};
```

Additionally, updated some of the TS to use interfaces + readonly to improve readability

```js
export interface StartEndDate {
  start_date: string;
  end_date: string;
};

export interface PayrollContract extends StartEndDate {
  readonly type: 'ON_PAYROLL';
  yearly_holidays: number;
};

export interface FreelanceContract extends StartEndDate {
  readonly type: 'FREELANCE';
  hourly_rate: number;
};

export type Contract = PayrollContract | FreelanceContract;
```